# ERROR: request not found in the TrackedRequests. We might be creating and closing webs on different threads

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, infopath

This is an error I receive from Sharepoint when I deploy a custom workflow to a forms library.  The workflow is very straightforward and doesn't do anything fancy.  I was reading from the an infopath form, but have since stripped down all non-essential code to see if I can get it working.  As far as I can tell, other workflows are fine (I've developed others on the same box and they are intact and functioning).  The design view of the workflow is as follows:

[alt text http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/7231/workflowv.jpg](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/7231/workflowv.jpg)

The error occurs after a task is successfully created.  This leads me to believe that there is an issue with the while loop, which is waiting for a boolean variable to become true (which is initially set to false).  Normally, when the task is altered in any way, the changed event will fire and change the variable to true, then the workflow will continue.  I receive this error on the start of this workflow:

> ERROR: request not found in the
>   TrackedRequests. We might be creating
>   and closing webs on different threads.
>   ThreadId = 9, Free call stack =    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.Release(SPRequest
>   request)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Close()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Dispose() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver.AutoStartWorkflow(SPItemEventProperties
>   properties, Boolean bCreate, Boolean
>   bChange, AssocType atyp)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver.AutoStartWorkflow(SPItemEventProperties
>   properties, Boolean bCreate, Boolean
>   bChange)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver.ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.RunItemEventRec...
>   ...eiver(SPItemEventReceiver receiver,
>   SPItemEventProperties properties,
>   SPEventContext context, String
>   receiverData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.RunItemEventReceiverHelper(Object
>   receiver, Object properties,
>   SPEventContext context, String
>   receiverData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevatedWrapper(Object
>   state)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken
>   userToken, Boolean bResetContext,
>   WaitCallback code, Object param)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken
>   userToken, CodeToRunElevated code)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.InvokeEventReceivers[ReceiverType](SPUserToken
>   userToken, RunEventReceiver
>   runEventReceiver, Obj...    ...ect
>   receivers, Object properties, Boolean
>   checkCancel)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.InvokeEventReceivers[ReceiverType](Byte[]
>   userTokenBytes, RunEventReceiver
>   runEventReceiver, Object receivers,
>   Object properties, Boolean
>   checkCancel)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.HandleEventCallback[ReceiverType,PropertiesType](Object
>   callbackData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadPool.WaitCallbackWrapper(Object
>   state)     at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)     at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object
>   userData)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(Execu..

I've searched high and low for an explanation, but cannot find anything that concretely fixes this problem.  It really is a straightforward workflow, with nothing special going on...maybe it's the form library it's attached to?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and found a [possible solution](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/07/solution-for-sharepoints-common.html).

Although we were disposing our SPSite and SPWeb objects properly, we forgot to dispose the BinaryStream we took of the SPFile object.

We are still seeing the same problem on SharePoint Designer workflows, even when they contain no actions. I have started [a separate thread for that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021033/investigating-the-root-cause-behind-sharepoints-request-not-found-in-the-tracke).